# Is the function floor(log n)! O(n), Ω(n), or Θ(n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am very confused as to how I can evaluate the floor of (log n)!

Comment: `floor` itself is basically O(1), so it'd depend on what algorithm is used to calculate `log n`.

Comment: I think he's asking about the function itself, not an algorithm to calculate the value.

Comment: But `floor` can be ignored here, since it essentially turns a continuous function into a set of piecewise constant functions.

Comment: I'd assume the calculation of the factorial is much harder than the `log`.

Comment: Does it make sense to talk of O(...) of a problem (as opposed to an algorithm)? It is not hard to find inefficient algorithms for a problem that would take more time than the O(...) suggests. On the other hand, the Omega(...) of a problem makes sense.

Comment: Big-oh notation *only* talks about growth of functions. Their use in algorithmic analysis is to provide bounds on the functions that model the running time of the algorithms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ignore the `floor`; since `x-1 < floor(x) <= x` for all `x`, you can easily show that if `g(x) = floor(f(x))`, then `g = Θ(f)`.

Using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), you can say that `(log n)!` is `Θ((log n)^(log n))`, which simplifies to `Θ(n^(log log n))` which is clearly `Ω(n)`.

(thanks to Mark Dickinson for correcting my horrible math; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/445932/78700as) for a proof).

Comment: `(log n) ^ (log n)` would be `n ^ (log log n)`, which grows faster than `n`.  Or put another way, `(log n)^(log n) > e^(log n) = n`, for sufficiently large `n`.